# Nginx/Load balancer coniguration for

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, load-balancing

I am trying to configure out load balancer to enable http(s) and web-socket connections.

Using this blog
http://blog.flux7.com/web-apps-websockets-with-aws-elastic-load-balancing

and following configuration but with SSL certificates.

[image: ELB Configuration]

The only problem is we have a configuration in Nginx which redirects http requests to https, which has stopped working as X-forwarded-proto is not supported by Load Balancer anymore.

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
  return 301 https://www-stg.example.com/$request_uri;
}
```

Any help on how this can be resolved?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show **your** load balancer configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Change your Load Balancer to Application Load Balancer as Application Load Balancer is a new product of AWS which supports Web Sockets so you don't have to create this work around to make Web Sockets to work.

https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/applicationloadbalancer/